# ColorBox HTML page Size Not Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I use ColorBox Jquery plugin to open a HTML file.
I use iframe attribute to open the HTMl page.
But the HTML page only occupies a part of the ColorBox and not the entire part.

The Code is

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:500, height:500 , overlayClose:true });       
    });
```

HTML code is

```
<div id='container'>
<div id="sign1" class="sign" style="background-image:url('images/log.jpg'); position:absolute; width:1440px; height:25px;">
</div>
<div id='text11' class='text'><font color='white'><a class='iframe' href="hello.html"> Sign Up </div></font>
</div>
```

Here is the Image

![preview]https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhHn1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:window.width, height:window.height , overlayClose:true });       
    });
```

Comment: Does not work, it reduces to a very small size almost like a button.